# Optimal configuration for PLL on LPC17xx

Tags: frequency, pll, lpc, nxp, configuration

I'm trying to write an algorithm that would pick the best available PLL0 configuration for the user based on F_in and F_cclk.

The manual says that I should pick higher F_ref if possible for a more stable PLL, for low frequency input clock. It doesn't specify what frequency is considered low, though.

Given the NXP's spreadsheet for PLL options calculation there are two variables: F_cco and m/n pair to use.

What is the optimal value to use (performance-wise? stability-wise? what does it change, actually?): bigger m/n vs. smaller m/n vs. bigger F_cco/pll divisor vs. smaller F_cco/pll divisor?

I don't care about USB special case for now.

TL;DR: what is a better option and why:

Given F_in = 12MHz and expected F_cclk = 100MHz

m=50, n=3, divisor=4 or m=325, n=26, divisor=3?

Comment: Have you tried measuring it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The best way to look at the issue is that the VCO (Voltage controller Oscillator) can be very sensitive to voltage ripple and spikes which translates directly into jitter.  the key to a good PLL is low output jitter, but there is a a compromise, a low jitter PLL will also be slow to lock.

So contrary to what Andy has to say, you must run the PLL at as high a divide ratio as possible.  The divider/count down circuit acts as a low pass filter and reduces jitter (actually it averages it) making the control of the VCO smoother.

here is a [PDF link](http://www.ece.tamu.edu/~spalermo/ecen620/lecture14_ee620_fracn_freq_synth.pdf)

Page 5 gives you this nugget "In integer-N PLLs, synthesizing tight channel spacings requires extremely low effective reference frequencies"

- tight channel spacings means low jitter.

and more:

This results in very low loop bandwidths and high divide ratios
• Slow PLL frequency switching time
• Large area passives
• High phase noise at low frequencies

they use these facts to derive the fact that a fractional - N frequency synthesis solves these issues ( the need for high divide ratio)

So yes, your manual is right.

Comment: I was reading that the PLL in the question was being used as a demodulator and in this situation, the phase detector should be run at the highest frequency. You say the op's manual is right but, "the manual says that I should pick higher F_ref if possible for a more stable PLL" and doesn't this go against what you say?

Comment: Also, last night when I wrote my answer it seemed that the device mentioned in the question was a stand-alone PLL - having finally got to my PC and had a look I realize that it isn't what I thought it was so I'm going to delete my answer because it is inappropriate for this device. Check your embedded link dude - it didn't work when I tried it but it could by general internet glitchiness.

Comment: So, summing up all that, does this configuration sound reasonable: m=500, n=24, divisor=5? That gets me to (2*500*12MHz)/24 == 500MHz on PLL output (with a top limit of 550MHz for this MCU) and 100MHz on F_cclk with 5x divisor. What am I losing if compared to lower values? If I get it right, it's just a slower lock time, I'd guess the energy consumption of pll will be a bit higher as well, right? And what I get is more stable output clock.